# If $\lambda$ is a weight of an irreducible $\mathbb{C}S_n$-module, and $\lambda_{i+1}=\lambda_i\pm 1$, then $\mu=s_i\lambda$ is not a weight?

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $V$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{C}S_n$-module, and $L_i$ the $i$th Jucys-Murphy element of $\mathbb{C}S_n$. A vector $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ is a weight of $V$ if there is a simulteanous eigenspace $V_\lambda$ in $V$ where $L_i$ acts as $\lambda_i$. Such $V_\lambda$ are one dimensional and spanned by some vector $v_\lambda$.

If $\mu=s_i\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{i-1},\lambda_{i+1},\lambda_i,\lambda_{i+2},\dots,\lambda_n)$, but $\lambda_{i+1}=\lambda_i\pm 1$, why is $\mu$ not a weight of $V$?

This is part of Corollary 2.2.3 of Kleshchev's Linear and Projective Representations of Symmetric Groups. He proves that $L(\lambda_i,\lambda_{i+1})$ is a one dimensional irreducible $\mathcal{H}_2$-module, and says it follows from the classification of $\mathcal{H}_2$-modules.

Here $\mathcal{H}_2=\langle x,y,s:xy=yx,\ s^2=1,\ sx=ys-1\rangle$, and if $\lambda_{i+1}=\lambda_i+1$, then $x,y,s$ act by $\lambda_i,\lambda_{i+1},-1$, respectively on a certain basis vector of $L(\lambda_i,\lambda_{i+1})$. But I don't see how this connects with $\mu$ and why it's not a weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the module $M$ he defines,
 $$M := \operatorname{Hom}_{S_{i-1}}(V(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_{i-1}), V(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_{i+1})),$$
is the space of copies of $V(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_{i-1})$  in $\operatorname{res}^{S_{i+1}}_{S_{i-1}} V(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_{i+1})$. In particular, if $s_i \lambda$ is a weight, then $M$ will "see" it.

He claims $M$ is irreducible as a $\mathcal B_i := \langle L_i, s_i, L_{i+1}\rangle$-module (using a technical theorem from the introduction), and is isomorphic to $N := \mathcal B_i v_\lambda$ (this isomoprhism is induced by the homomorphism $M \to N$ given by $f \mapsto f(v_\lambda)$).

Once you believe these two claims, it falls out of the classification of irreducible representations of $\mathcal H_2 \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal B_i$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I understand the details behind the claims he makes in the proof, so I believe the two claims you restate above. But it's the "falls out of the classification of irreducible $\mathcal{H}_2$-modules" where I don't understand how it ties back to $\mu$. Assuming $N$ is isomorphic to either of the $1$-dimensional representations in the preceding exposition, since $\lambda_{i+1}=\lambda_i\pm 1$, I don't see the contradiction to $\mu$ being a weight.

Comment: @JoieHwang If $\mu$ were a weight, then it would show up in $N$, because $N$ is isomorphic to $M$, and $M$ must include the $\mu$-weights.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you know $\mu$ doesn't show up in $N$? I think this is my fundamental confusion.

Comment: @JoieHwang I'm not sure what precisely is confusing you. $N$ is irreducible, so $\mu$ can't show up in $N$ by the classification of irreducible representations.

Comment: Do you mean that assuming $\mu$ is a weight, the weight space $V_\mu$ is not contained in $N$? So the issue is that if so, the weight vector $v_\mu\in N$, but then by inflation $xv_\mu=L_iv_\mu=\lambda_{i+1}v_\mu$, contrary to the fact that $x$ acts by $\lambda_i$ on $N=L(\lambda_i,\lambda_{i+1})$?

Comment: @JoieHwang What I'm saying is $V_\mu$ must be contained in $N$ by the chain of reasoning that we had starting from $M$. But if $V_\mu$ were nonzero, then the $\mathcal H_2$-module $N$ would contain both a $(\lambda_i, \lambda_{i+1})$ and a $(\lambda_{i+1}, \lambda_i)$-weight, which cannot be irreducible. Is your question actually about proving the latter claim?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure this is my problem, but does my reasoning in the previous comment explain this? Since Corollary 2.2.3(ii) assumes $\lambda_{i+1}=\lambda_i\pm 1$, then $N=L(\lambda_i,\lambda_{i+1})=\mathbb{C}v$ where $xv=\lambda_i v$, $yv=\lambda_{i+1}v$, $sv=\pm v$, but assumiing $V_\mu\neq 0$, $v_\mu=cv\in N$ for some scalar $c$, giving the contradiction above?

Comment: Okay, so for simplicity, note that there is an automorphism of $\mathcal H_2$ given by $x \mapsto x+c, y \mapsto y+c, s \mapsto s$ for $c \in \mathbb C$, and similarly another automorphism given by $x \mapsto y, y \mapsto x, s \mapsto -s$, so that we may look without loss of generality at irreducible $\mathcal H_2$-modules $W$ with a $(0, 1)$-weight.

Comment: So we have $w \in W$ with $xw=0, yw=w$. If $sw$ is not a scalar multiple of $w$, then $x(sw) = (sy-1)w = sw-w$ and $y(sw) = (sx+1)w=w$. So $W$ has a basis given by $\{w, sw\}$. But then $x(sw-w) = sw-w$, $y(sw-w)=0$, and $s(sw-w)=w-sw$, so $W$ is not irreducible.

Comment: Note that the category of finite dimensional representations of $\mathcal H_2$ is *not* semisimple; the $2$-dimensional representation $W$ has a subrepresentation spanned by $sw-w$ which has no complement.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I was not aware of those autos of $\mathcal{H}_2$, but the explanation is now clear to me.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: @JoieHwang Obviously, the reasoning without using those automorphisms is identical; just messier. :)